# Will the subclass method automaticlly inherit the decorator of the abstractmethod in super class?

Tags: python

I have a `@retry` decorator which is defined by myself.

```py
class AbstractFunction(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    
    @abstractmethod
    @retry
    def run(self):
        pass
```

Now, if I have a subclass like this, will the run method inherit `@retry` automatically?

```py
def RealFunction(AbstractFunction):

    def run(self):
        #the real function code
        pass
```

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: The decorator is just a shortcut for adding code to the method definition. There's no way that can be inherited.

Comment: @martineau yeah, it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AbstractFunction.run` refers to one object, whatever `retry` returned when it was called. The definition is essentially the same as

```
class AbstractFunction(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def run(self):
        pass

    run = abstractmethod(retry(run))
```

`RealFunction.run`, on the other hand, refers to an entirely unrelated function *also* named `run`. `retry` was never called.'

If you want some sort of inherited retry behavior, define *two* functions. `AbstractFunction.run` does nothing except call a hook that the child needs to define:

```
class AbstractFunction(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @retry
    def run(self):
        return self._run_implementation()

    @abstractmethod
    def _run_implementation(self):
        pass


class RealFunction(AbstractFunction):
    def _run_implemenation(self):
        ...
```

Here, `run` is neither abstract nor overwritten, but *does* get replaced by whatever `retry` returns. So when you try to call `RealFunction().run()`, it's actually `AbstractFunction.run` that gets called, which does nothing but call `RealFunction._run_implemenation`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood. If I want to let the run method in the subclass act as same as the  AbstractFunction.run. I should not overwrite it or just call supper.run when overwrite it.

Comment: Right; the retry logic is provided by the parent, while the code being retried is provided by the child.