# Inheriting Decorator from Overwritten Subclass Function

Tags: python, inheritance, interface, decorator, python-decorators

I have a decorator that performs a couple of logging operations,

```
def event_logger(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # get the logger
        logger = logging.getLogger()

        logger.info("Some log")

        # execute the function
        return_value = function(*args, **kwargs)

        logger.info("Some log")
        return return_value

    return wrapper
```

Now, I have implemented a bunch of `processors` that each inherit from an interface (Factory Pattern).

My interface looks like this,

```
class IProcessor(ABC):
    @property
    def _logger(self):
        return logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        """
        Execute processing operation
        """
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses must implement process method")
```

An example of a processor (subclass) would look like this,

```
class TestProcessor(IProcessor):
    @event_logger
    def process(self):
        self._logger.info("TestPreProcessor")
```

As shown here, the `@event_logger` decorator has been added to the `process` method of my subclass. This works, but it would mean that each time I have a new `processor`, I would need to remember to add the decorator.

Is there anyway I can avoid this maybe by adding the decorator to the `process` method of the interface or something? I know this will probably not work, since the subclass will be overwriting this method though. Is there some way that I can achieve this?

Comment: you could use a metaclass in `IProcessor` to automatically apply `@event_logger` to `process` method of subclasses

Comment: @Anentropic Could you post an answer about how this is done? I am not really familiar with metaclasses, to be honest.

Comment: here is an answer which proposes a way to do something similar without metaclass https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612660/202168

Comment: The decorator is not part of the final method; it's just a function application, the same as `process = event_logger(process)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the decorator in the `__init_subclass__` method of your interface class.

If the methods to be decorated are always "final": that is, they don't call the `super()` version of themselves, it is easy to do. If they do call their super-versions, which could also be decorated - then you have to add some state-checking logic to avoid performing the decorator code more than once (that may be tricky)

```py
class IProcessor(ABC):

    _methods_to_add_logging = ("process", )

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        for method_name in __class__._methods_to_add_logging:
            method = getattr(cls, method_name, None)
            if not method:
                continue
            method = event_logger(method)
            setattr(cls, method_name, method)

    @property
    def _logger(self):
        return logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        """
        Execute processing operation
        """
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses must implement process method")
```

Comment: I copied your code and tried to inherit from it using my `TestPreProcessor` and I get this error,
`TypeError: TestProcessor.__init_subclass__() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: There is one extra "cls" argument in that call. I am editing it out now.

Comment: There still seems to be some issues,
`RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`

Comment: yes . .I had edited `cls` out of the wrong place earlier. Anyway, if you are not combining this with other classes, you might just suppress that super call anyway.